Custom type in angular formly
I'm struggling to find solution for several days, without success.
I'm using Angular Formly, Angular Material and Angular 17 for making mat-select as custom type. When I'm using the mat-select control as custom type it throws error:
Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.
    at getMatFormFieldMissingControlError (form-field.mjs:422:12)
    at MatFormField._assertFormFieldControl (form-field.mjs:673:19)
    at MatFormField.ngAfterContentChecked (form-field.mjs:581:14)
    at callHookInternal (core.mjs:5136:14)
    at callHook (core.mjs:5167:9)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:5118:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:5068:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12787:21)
    at detectChangesInView$1 (core.mjs:12970:9)
    at detectChangesInViewIfAttached (core.mjs:12933:5)

If I don't use as custom type I don't have problems. As I saw, the above error is thrown when angular formly custom type is defined.
I'm having the following structure in my code.
export let AppInjector: Injector;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BlockUIModule.forRoot({
      delayStart: 100,
      delayStop: 0
    }),
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      timeOut: 10000,
      positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right',
      closeButton: true,
      enableHtml: true
    }),
    SharedModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    provideAnimationsAsync()
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    AppInjector = this.injector;
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ProvidersModule,
    AngularFormlyModule
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ProvidersModule,
    AngularFormlyModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    NgApexchartsModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    NgApexchartsModule
  ]
})
export class ProvidersModule { }

@NgModule({
    providers: [
    ],
    declarations: [
        AngularFormlySelectComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        FormlyModule,
        FormlyMaterialModule,
        FormlyMatDatepickerModule,
        FormlyMatToggleModule
    ],
    imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormlyMaterialModule,
        FormlyMatDatepickerModule,
        FormlyMatToggleModule,
        ProvidersModule,
        FormlyModule.forRoot({
            types: [
                {
                    name: 'select',
                    component: AngularFormlySelectComponent,
                    wrappers: ['form-field']
                }
            ]
        })
    ]
})
export class AngularFormlyModule { }


@Component({
    selector: 'app-angular-formly-select',
    template: `
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>{{ props.placeholder }}</mat-label>
          <mat-select [formControl]="formControl" [formlyAttributes]="field" (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)">
            <mat-option>(...)</mat-option>
            @for (item of filter; track item) {
                <mat-option [value]="item.value">{{ item.label }}</mat-option>
              }
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    `
  })
export class AngularFormlySelectComponent extends FieldType<FieldTypeConfig> implements OnInit  {

  filter: any=[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.filter = this.props?.options ? this.props.options : EMPTY;
  }

  onSelectionChange(event: any) {
    if (this.props.onChange) {
      this.props.onChange(this.field, event);
    }
  }
}


response of the form:
{
    "Id": 3,
    "Fields": [
        {
            "key": "SearchText",
            "id": "SearchText",
            "className": "col-md-3",
            "type": "input",
            "props": {
                "label": "Search",
                "placeholder": "Search",
                "type": null,
                "options": []
            },
            "validators": {
                "validation": [
                    "novalidation"
                ]
            },
            "method": null
        },
        {
            "key": "DateFrom",
            "id": "DateFrom",
            "className": "col-md-3",
            "type": "datepicker",
            "props": {
                "label": "From Date",
                "placeholder": "Insert from Date",
                "type": null,
                "options": []
            },
            "validators": {
                "validation": [
                    "novalidation"
                ]
            },
            "method": null
        },
        {
            "key": "DateTo",
            "id": "DateTo",
            "className": "col-md-3",
            "type": "datepicker",
            "props": {
                "label": "To Date",
                "placeholder": "Insert to Date",
                "type": null,
                "options": []
            },
            "validators": {
                "validation": [
                    "novalidation"
                ]
            },
            "method": null
        },
        {
            "key": "ClientId",
            "id": "ClientId",
            "className": "col-md-3",
            "type": "select",
            "props": {
                "label": "Client",
                "placeholder": "Choose client",
                "type": null,
                "options": [
                    {
                        "value": "3",
                        "label": "Microsoft",
                        "defaultValue": null
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "1",
                        "label": "Coca Cola",
                        "defaultValue": null
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "2",
                        "label": "Apple",
                        "defaultValue": null
                    }
                ]
            },
            "validators": {
                "validation": [
                    "novalidation"
                ]
            },
            "method": "GetClients"
        },
        {
            "key": "BudgetTypeId",
            "id": "BudgetTypeId",
            "className": "col-md-3",
            "type": "select",
            "props": {
                "label": "Budget Type",
                "placeholder": "Choose Budget Type",
                "type": null,
                "options": [
                    {
                        "value": "2",
                        "label": "Money (Denars)",
                        "defaultValue": null
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "3",
                        "label": "Money (Dollars)",
                        "defaultValue": null
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "4",
                        "label": "Money (EURs)",
                        "defaultValue": null
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "1",
                        "label": "Hours",
                        "defaultValue": null
                    }
                ]
            },
            "validators": {
                "validation": [
                    "novalidation"
                ]
            },
            "method": "GetBudgetTypes"
        },
        {
            "key": "StatusId",
            "id": "StatusId",
            "className": "col-md-3",
            "type": "select",
            "props": {
                "label": "Status",
                "placeholder": "Choose Status",
                "type": null,
                "options": [
                    {
                        "value": "1",
                        "label": "Not configured",
                        "defaultValue": null
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "3",
                        "label": "Closed",
                        "defaultValue": null
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "4",
                        "label": "Overdue",
                        "defaultValue": null
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "2",
                        "label": "Active",
                        "defaultValue": null
                    }
                ]
            },
            "validators": {
                "validation": [
                    "novalidation"
                ]
            },
            "method": "GetStatuses"
        },
        {
            "key": "ExceededBudget",
            "id": "ExceededBudget",
            "className": "col-md-3",
            "type": "checkbox",
            "props": {
                "label": "Projects with exceeded budget",
                "placeholder": "Search projects with exceeded budget",
                "type": "NULL",
                "options": []
            },
            "validators": {
                "validation": [
                    "novalidation"
                ]
            },
            "method": null
        },
        {
            "key": "ExceededBudgetPrediction",
            "id": "ExceededBudgetPrediction",
            "className": "col-md-3",
            "type": "checkbox",
            "props": {
                "label": "Projects with exceeded budget prediction",
                "placeholder": "Search projects with exceeded budget prediction",
                "type": "NULL",
                "options": []
            },
            "validators": {
                "validation": [
                    "novalidation"
                ]
            },
            "method": null
        }
    ],
    "ClientModel": "ProjectSearchModel"
}


You could solve this problem by making the component completely independent using standalone: true this will give you the power to freely using the component inside Formly without any external dependencies.
First convert the component to standalone:
@Component({
    selector: 'app-angular-formly-select',
    imports: [MatFormFieldModule, MatSelectModule, ReactiveFormsModule], // do add more modules if needed!
    standalone: true, //<- changed here!
    template: `
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>{{ props.placeholder }}</mat-label>
          <mat-select [formControl]="formControl" [formlyAttributes]="field" (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)">
            <mat-option>(...)</mat-option>
            @for (item of filter; track item) {
                <mat-option [value]="item.value">{{ item.label }}</mat-option>
              }
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    `
  })
export class AngularFormlySelectComponent extends FieldType<FieldTypeConfig> implements OnInit  {

  filter: any=[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.filter = this.props?.options ? this.props.options : EMPTY;
  }

  onSelectionChange(event: any) {
    if (this.props.onChange) {
      this.props.onChange(this.field, event);
    }
  }
}

Then we need to remove the component from the declarations array and move it to the imports array. Since it's standalone, it can only be imported:
@NgModule({
    providers: [
    ],
    declarations: [
    ],
    exports: [
        FormlyModule,
        FormlyMaterialModule,
        FormlyMatDatepickerModule,
        FormlyMatToggleModule
    ],
    imports: [
        AngularFormlySelectComponent, // <- changed here!
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormlyMaterialModule,
        FormlyMatDatepickerModule,
        FormlyMatToggleModule,
        ProvidersModule,
        FormlyModule.forRoot({
            types: [
                {
                    name: 'select',
                    component: AngularFormlySelectComponent,
                    wrappers: ['form-field']
                }
            ]
        })
    ]
})
export class AngularFormlyModule { }


Thanks. Now I get the following: Error: compareWith must be a function.
at getMatSelectNonFunctionValueError (select.mjs:79:12)
at set compareWith (select.mjs:195:19)
at applyValueToInputField (core.mjs:4035:30)
at Object.ngOnChangesSetInput [as setInput] (core.mjs:4113:5)
at writeToDirectiveInput (core.mjs:11048:17)
at setInputsForProperty (core.mjs:12346:9)
at elementPropertyInternal (core.mjs:11647:9)
at ɵɵproperty (core.mjs:21169:9)
at FormlyFieldSelect_Template (ngx-formly-material-select.mjs:86:28)
at executeTemplate (core.mjs:11223:9)
